# Custom papers are not being recognized

Tags: printer

My workflow requires me to work with custom paper sizes. I have about 12.
I just bought a new HP computer, one of the first things I did was setup these paper sizes.

I created them using the "Print server properties" in Control Panel > Devices and Printers. They all show up in the list on that dialog, but not in my printer's paper list.

Oddly so, some of them are being recognized by my printers and some not!
I even tried selecting the xerox printer that I need it for, and then create it, but even then it didnt work

What could be the reason for this?

1. Why would they not show up
2. Why would some show and some not show!?

I'm running Windows 10 64bit. I have a Xerox phaser 4510 and HP officejet 8600